# Deploy lambda to AWS as stage dev?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, aws-lambda, serverless

I've created a serverless function with `SAM` under `Outputs` you can specify how the URL comes out. I've added `Dev` to this lambda as it is not in staging nor should be in production it is part of testing ATM. Once I've deployed it I have `URL` which is specifies it is `Prod`... How can I fix this and get it to be in `/Dev`

```
Outputs:
  TimedTextRecsnApi:
      Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Timed Text Recsn Function"
      Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Dev/"
```

[image]

**Update**
I've found that I had an extra copy of `Outputs` in my `template.yaml`. After removing it the service deployed under `/Dev` but I kept getting `forbidden`. On AWS Lambda it still showed as under `/Prod` and once I've changed my `template.yaml` to have `/Prod` the service started to respond again. I don'y know what's going on.